# Use netty for parsing XML strings

Tags: java, xml, tcp, netty

I am getting messages over TCP in standard xml format, which I am listening to over my netty client. How should my pipeline be written so that I can parse strings starting and ending with `<abc>....</abc>` ?

I am guessing there should be a String decoder and another custom handler (netty defined or otherwise) that deals with the parsing of XML from the TCP stream.

Something like the following?

```
public Bootstrap createBootstrap(final Bootstrap b, EventLoopGroup eventLoop) {
    b.group(workerGroup);
    b.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
    ReconnectionClient reconnectionClient = new ReconnectionClient(this);
    b.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
        @Override
        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
            ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
            pipeline.addLast(reconnectionClient);
            pipeline.addLast(new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));             
            pipeline.addLast(new ClientHandler()); // deals with String parsing                
        }
    });

    // Use command line arguments to pass the socket
    b.connect(serverIP, serverPort).addListener(new ConnectionListener(this));
    return b;
}
```

The second part of my question is how do I parse individual XML strings that are transmitted over TCP? As in, what code should be written in ClientHandler() that implements this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to decode XML with netty you can use the inbuild [XML-decoder](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/codec-xml/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/xml/XmlDecoder.java) (this handler doesn't need a StringDecoder). If you want to start process the XML-document after an `<abc>` tag you can simply wait for a [XmlElementStart](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/xml/XmlElementStart.html) object whichs name is `abc`. The same thing goes for the close tag but with a [XmlElementEnd](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/xml/XmlElementEnd.html) object.